# class initialization function definition in java

Tags: java, android, anonymous-class

I'm getting the error "Abstract methods do not specify a body" with the below code....

```
    DCWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public abstract void launchExternalBrowser(String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

`MyWebViewClient` is an abstract class.  I'm wondering what the above code is doing exactly.  It's clearly intending on defining the function for the class... can I just put any code within the `new MyWebViewClient() { }` to define variables and other functions?

What other awesome things can be done in here?

Answer (score 6):

Just remove `abstract` and it will work. If the method `launchExternalBrowser` is not defined in `MyWebViewCLient` you should also remove `@Override` annotation. `@Override` means that you override a method which is defined in an extended class hierarchy.

`DCWebView.setWebViewClient` methods requires an object of type `MyWebViewClient` as a parameter. By writing `new MyWebClient() { .. }` you create an instance of an anonymous class which extends `MyWebViewClient`.

Anonymous classes are (almost) the same as "normal" classes. You can define both new variables and methods there. The main difference is that an anonymous class is defined in a place where it is used (there is no external class definition and because of that it has no name, it is "anonymous") and it is used only in this one place (as there is no external definition it cannot be used elsewhere).

Anonymous classes are very commonly used in Java, however this is something a little more advanced. As [esaj said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202161/class-initialization-function-definition-in-java/8202191#8202191) in his answer it is a good idea to read something about this. There is plenty of information in the web e.g. [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) or [here](http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/09/anonymous-inner-classes/).

Comment: It doesn't work, then I get the error `The method launchExternalBrowser(String) of type new MyWebViewClient(){} must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: You need to pick up a book on Java and read for a while. Your method does not override anything in MyWebViewClient, so you need to delete the @Override annotation.

Comment: Does `launchExternalBrowser` override a method in it's parent class? If not, remove the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Ok, then try removing `@Override`. `@Override` means that you override a method which is defined in `MyWebViewClient`. I assumed `launchExternalBrowser` is defined there, if it is not then you cannot ovveride it and thus should remove `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract method is used to define a method without implementation. A concrete (non-abstract) class extending from an abstract class must then implement the abstract methods of the extended abstract class. The implementation for the defined method is written without the `abstract`-keyword in its method signature.

You probably should read through the Java SE tutorial about abstract classes and methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

> can I just put any code within the new MyWebViewClient() { } to define
>   variables and other functions?

Yes, but there's another catch: as it seems you are giving your "anonymous" implementation of MyWebViewClient to another class's (static?) method DCWebView.setWebViewClient(), the DCWebView probably is only aware of the methods declared in the (abstract?) MyWebViewClient, and cannot access any other methods, even if they are public. However, if you want to break down the anonymous implementation of the MyWebViewClient to separate private methods and use member-variables within it, you are free to do so.